# Checking whether a unique data is present in a json file

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net

I need to check whether a word is present in a JSON file or not. So if I'm searching for "root", then even though the word "byroots" contain root, it should give me false. 
Here's my code

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("filename.json"))
{
    string json1 = r.ReadToEnd();
    if (json1.Contains("root"))
    {
        filename = path + @"" + branch + "-" + testsuite.Title + ".json";
    }
}
```

I've also tried this condition:-

```
if (json1.IndexOf(testsuite.Title, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

But I'm getting the same results.

Here's the json data

```
{
"LV": {
    "build_number": "20180517.1",
    "blah_blah": "blah",
    "name": "byroots",
    }
}
```

Comment: How's the json data look like? You want to return true only if `root` exists as a whole word only? What if there is some thing like `root check` exist in the json, should it return true or false?

Comment: I've added the json data now. And It should return true only if root exists as a single word in "name" keyword. @Chetan Ranpariya

Comment: I think you should search for `"root"` in json. Or may be `"name": "roots"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Regex

```
var pattern = @"*root*";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("filename.json"))
{
 string json1 = r.ReadToEnd();
 if (rgx.IsMatch(json1))
 {
    filename = path + @"" + branch + "-" + testsuite.Title + ".json";
 }
}
```